# Can't use boost::bind to access boost::tuple elements

Tags: c++, boost, bind, tuples

I'm using the i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 compiler on OSX.6 (I've upgraded a 10.5 install and carried over the previous dev toolkit).

I'm including these libraries in my implementation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
```

I have a tuple that looks like this:

```
typedef boost::tuple<double, unsigned long, unsigned long, char> myTupleType;
```

I have a vector of such tuples:

```
std::vector<myTupleType> theTupleVector;
```

I have a method that should retrieve values as such:

```
template <typename T,int i>
class accessTupleElement
{ 
public: 
    typedef typename boost::tuples::element<i,T>::type result_type;

    template <typename U> result_type operator()(const U& u) const
    { 
    // Select the ith element of the tuple T and return it 
    return boost::get<i>(u); 
    } 
};
```

I then attempt to do such wonderful things as:

```
std::find_if(startIter, endIter, boost::bind(std::equal<unsigned long>, boost::bind(accessTupleElement<myTupleType, 1>(), _1), 123L));
```

startIter and endIter are the start and end of my vector of tuples. I would presume this would bind the function object with the value of the iterator, evaluate to the desired value of the tuple, and compare it to 123.

It's MADDENING that all I get is the following error message regarding my inner bind:

```
no matching function for call to 'bind(<unresolved overloaded function type>, boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, accessTupleElement<boost::tuples::tuple<double, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, char, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>, 1>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::arg<1> > >, boost::arg<2>&)'
```

I don't get it, how can the compiler get confused? There's only one identifier called accessTupleElement, and I've followed all the boost and internet documentation I could find trying to resolve this. How is this resolved?

Comment: Are you quite certain the problem is with your inner bind call, and not the outer one?  <unresolved overloaded function type> seems aweful suspicious, and it is refering to `std::equal<unsigned long>`.

Comment: How do you figure it's referring to the std::equal? Am I reading the error wrong?

Comment: @Matthew Because the type of the second argument (`boost::_bi::bind_t`) looks like the return type of the inner `bind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
std::equal<unsigned long>
```

to

```
std::equal<unsigned long>()
```

---

Well, `std::equal` is a function template, hence the error message. You probably wanted `std::equal_to`, so use the following:

```
std::equal_to<unsigned long>()
```

Comment: Could you explain why the first wrong and the second is correct?

Comment: Nope, "no matching function call to 'equal()'"